# clip raster to polygon with 3 srids

Tags: postgis, raster, polygon, clip

I have 70 raster landsat images with srid: 32647,32648,32649 and want to clip raster to polygon (shapefile, srid: 4326) in postgis.

I imported all raster into 1 table with parameter -s : 32648, transform srid of shapefile to 32648 but the result is not as I expected ( only overlap 40% the polygon)

So How can I fix that problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you used `raster2pgsql` to import the data, `-s`is **NOT** the right option to reproject the data into one single CRS.

You have assigned a new srid, but not recalculated the coordinates: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/using_raster_dataman.html

Instead, use `gdalwarp -s_srs old_srs -t_srs new_srs srcfile destfile` to reproject two of your rasters to the CRS of the third. Then you can import all of them into one table.

Comment: is there anyway to do it fast ? becasue it's long to do it file by file

Comment: Surely. On Wndows: `for %%N in (*.tif) DO gdalwarp -of vrt -s_srs ... -t_srs ... %%N D:\Karten\gdal\%%~nN.vrt`. Linux and Mac might have a different syntax for the loop.

Comment: I tried and got this error :

ERROR: rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment

SQL state: XX000

Comment: Did you get the error executing gdalwarp or when importing into Postgis?

Comment: Hi Andre, both command are fine. I get error when run st_clip() and st_union() query

Comment: If you load the reprojected rasters and the shapefile into a GIS software like QGIS, do they overlap as expected? BTW the shapefile must be reprojected to EPSG:32648 too.

Comment: I use st_transform(geom,32648) to clip

Comment: I reprojected the shapefile to 32648 too, but had the same error  rt_raster_from_two_rasters

Comment: It might be that the raster cells of your three sources do not mach exactly after reprojecting. See http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2014-June/039292.html and follow-ups.

Comment: I've got this one after that 
ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 14352.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your rasters without the -s option. raster2pgsql should automatically assign them the right SRID. You can check after the load is complete with ST_SRID(rast). Once they are imported with their own right SRID, you just have to ST_Transform(geom, ST_SRID(rast)) the polygon before cliping.

If in any case the importer do not assign each raster it's proper SRID you can reassign them with ST_SetSRID().

Comment: I think it's not solution because I tried it and get another error: invalid memory alloc request size

Comment: How big are your rasters in term of memory?